# Slack API upload file, by channel name instead of channel ID?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm writing code to upload a file to Slack using their API, which is documented [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload). The documentation says:

> Comma-separated list of channel names or IDs

I've been able to get it to work using channel IDs, like so:

```
channels=G01NAQEQZER
```

but I want to be able to specify the channels using their names instead of IDs, so I've tried:

```
channels=team-dev
```

and...

```
channels=#team-dev
```

but they both didn't work, giving the error:

```
channel_not_found
```

If the documentation is correct, I should be able to specify channels by their names instead of their IDs. Does anyone know how to specify channel names in the file upload request? The documentation doesn't give an example using channel names.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the documentation says names are possible but I don’t think it actually works, and in fact the latest API is very focused on IDs everywhere so this may be deliberate and the documentation is stale? Their general advice is not to rely on the name of the channel because it can change, instead you should store and refer to the IDs only.